# React Native: How to remove token with AsyncStorage with JWT ?

Tags: javascript, cookies, react-native, local-storage, jwt

I am currently storing my React Native token like so using `var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');`:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.token)
```

And I'm not sure if this is the correct way for React Native to check if the token is stored, but in the Chrome browser's Developer Tools, under Application and then Storage's Cookies, it shows a token and its value.

Then in order to remove the token, I do the following:

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')
```

yet even if I refresh the Storage's Cookies' page, the token still shows.

Is it being removed but am I viewing the token incorrectly or is it not being removed at all? If so what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you call the AsyncStorage.removeItem? Maybe you actually not calling it.

Comment: @NinetyHH I call it by `import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'`. Sorry, was that what you were asking?

Comment: Try adding the callback to removeItem and console log some output to make sure everything is working properly.

`AsyncStorage.removeItem('token', (err) => console.log('finished', err));`

Also provide more of your code so we can see the full cycle. How you get, set, and remove the token.

Comment: @TylerBuchea I tried the error log as you suggested but err logged as null. As for the full cycle, I just do exactly as the code I provided in the original post, where in the `componentWillMount`, I `AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.token)` and there is a button on another .js file where I simply do `AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')` once the button is clicked on.

Comment: Please also note that you should be storing things like tokens in some form of [encrypted storage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#storing-sensitive-info)

Answer (score 1):

Just use AsyncStorage.removeItem('token'). It worked for me.